# Convert file with integers written in ascii to binary file of integers

Tags: files, text-processing, utilities, conversion, binary

I have a file that contains a long list of integers written in ascii separated with newlines, like such:

```
-175
2
-19345
345592
-45
2355
```

etc...

I want to convert this file into a "binary" file containing the same integers, written as actual 4 byte integers.

What command-line tool can I use to achieve this?

Comment: You need to specify the endian-ness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
perl -pe '$_=pack"l",$_' < infile > outfile
```

Uses the local endianness. Use `l>` instead of `l` for big-endian, and `l<` for little-endian.

See `perldoc -f pack` for more info.

<sub>Note that it's `l` as in lowercase `L` (for *long integer*), not the `1` digit.</sub>

```
$ printf '%s\n' 1234 -2 | perl -pe '$_=pack"l",$_'| od -vtd4
0000000        1234          -2
0000010
$ printf '%s\n' 1234 -2 | perl -pe '$_=pack"l>",$_'| od -vtx1
0000000 00 00 04 d2 ff ff ff fe
0000010
```

Comment: With `l`, in my 64-bit machine: `perl -MConfig -e 'print $Config{longsize}'` , result is `8`.

Comment: @Gnouc, Yes `l` is **etymologically** for _long integer_ from the time where `long`s where 32bit wide. `l` has stayed and is guaranteed to stay 32bit wide even on systems where `long`s are wider (so `l` no longer means `long` in practice). Use `l!` if you want your system/compiler's `long`s

Answer (score 2):

Another `perl`:

```
$ perl -pe '$_ = pack("i", $_)' file
```

`i` represents signed integer value (which is represent at least 4 bytes, depend on local C compiler). Use `l` option like [@Stéphane Chazelas's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149189/38906) for always use 32-bit.

Comment: `i` is not guaranteed to be 4-byte wide. `l` is

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Yes, add note in my answer.

Comment: The `-l` option adds unwanted `0x0a` bytes to the  output.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas you are using a Unicode locale.

Comment: @hildred, yes, as a matter of fact, I am, but the `0x0a`s are the newline characters added by `-l` regardless of the locale.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: The OP don't provide his/her requirement about this, so I still add `-l`.

Comment: He says _convert to binary files_. I don't think there's room for newline characters in there.