# Create a binary input file from hdparm's --read-sector option

Tags: data-recovery, hdparm

I'm currently trying hard to rescue a very big file off a HDD which is about to die (clicking sounds). The read failure is caused by just **a small couple defective sectors**.
As the backup I could retrieve is way too old, my first plan was to get the file off there *even with* the corrupt data. **`PhotoRec`** turned out to be the ideal choice for this job since it indeed managed to recover the *whole* file. (`testdisk` was an epic fail, as it would've simply cut off the file where the error was detected)
Having retrieved the (partly corrupt) file onto the intact target HDD, the next steps to take were:

- use `hdparm --read-sector <device>` and create binary data files from its output
- use the valid data from these to repair the (few) corrupt sectors using a hex editor like `Okteta`.

And indeed, raw-read routines of `hdparm` (I used **v9.43**) (`--read-sector`) *could* be convinced to read the data off the (few) bad sectors on that one erroneous cylinder, but only gave me back a true **ascii** file. There is no way I know of *directly* getting the output to a binary file to perform the second step described above. Moreover, all words in the output files turned out to be **byte-swapped** (x86-32 here on Linux; **fixed in v9.45**, cf. [this older entry](https://sourceforge.net/p/hdparm/bugs/51/) in bug tracker).

Fortunately though, there is a way to make it work even with v9.43 and earlier, by using `hdparm`'s `--verbose` option, which (at the `incoming_data` line) will allow the hex values to get output exactly as read, in *correct* byte order!
So this is what I came up with so far, to read 50 sectors starting from 5000:

```
i=0
while [[ $((i++)) -lt 50 ]]; do
  sudo hdparm --verbose --read-sector $((5000+i)) /dev/sdb 2>&1 | 
  grep 'incoming_data' | cut -f2- -d: | sed 's/^  //' | 
  tee -a ascdata1_nl
done
tr '\n' ' ' < ascdata1_nl > ascdata1
```

Caveat: First file, `ascdata1_nl`, still contains **newline** characters. When the loop is finished, after transforming the newlines  into spaces, `ascdata1` will now contain the values as needed. Now byte by byte gets written into a .bin file:

```
 while read -d ' ' hexbyte; do printf "\x$hexbyte" | tee -a bindata.bin; done < ascdata1
```

The result will be a true binary file which can (e. g. with 'Okteta') be used to replace the (erroneous) zeroed areas in the file.

Short answer: **it works** that way.

Still, this procedure appears a bit over-complicated to me (?).

Any simpler way to obtain a binary file from a `--read-sector` "hex" dump?

- Using `perl`, I am sure the `--verbose` option in `hdparm` can be omitted since `pack()` / `unpack()` will do a fine job. (Just I haven't managed to do this with byte *pairs*)
- `dd conv=swab` : I also gave this `dd` option a try, which will unfortunately swap nibbles only, turning `a6b8 d6b7` into (useless) `6a8b 6d7b`.

Comment: What?  `hdparm --read-sector` isn't going to have any easier time reading a bad sector than anything else.  You want `ddrescue`, which can at least skip the bad block and come back to it later, retrying until it hopefully works.

Comment: Well, the most important thing to me was, that in the `hdparm` manual (I read it thoroughly several times), there was something explained about `hdparm` using an *extremely low-level approach* to read sectors when using `--read-sector`. So frankly, I wasn't sure (or better: much too skeptical) about whether `ddrescue` would use a likewise low-level approach or one or more tiers higher. Needless to say that the lowest tier was just good enough to get something useable out of those few corrupt sectors.

Comment: The man page is a bit misleading then.  It doesn't do anything magic.  It only crafts the command and sends it down itself instead of letting the kernel do it.  The actual command the drive sees is exactly the same.

Comment: Well, this is just what I wasn't sure about two weeks ago.

Comment: Dear @psusi & @syntaxerror, The `hdparm` [man page](http://man.he.net/man8/hdparm) states in part, _hdparm will issue a low-level read (completely bypassing the usual block layer read/write mechanisms) for the specified sector. This can be used to definitively check whether a given sector is bad (media error) or not (doing so through the usual mechanisms can sometimes give false positives)._ I recently had a drive that returned I/O errors when reading certain sectors with `hexdump` or `dd` that `hdparm --read-sector` was able to read successfully: https://asciinema.org/a/182611 .

Comment: Corrected video link: https://asciinema.org/a/183530 (Sorry, cannot edit my comment at this point apparently.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have GNU sed, you can try (*not really tested*):

```
 hdparm --read-sector $SECTOR /dev/sdb | \
  sed -r -e "0,/succeeded/d" -e 's/(\S\S)(\S\S)/\2\1/g' | \
  xxd -r -p >> bindata.bin
```

The `sed` call deletes everything up to the `succeeded` line and then byte-swaps the output. The `xxd -r -p` call translates plain hexadecimal code to binary data.